# How does RequestMapping work without EnableWebMvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I see **@RequestMapping** works without having annotated **@EnableWebMvc** at Java Configuration class level. This looks like **@EnableWebMvc** is no more required. Can anyone make me understand the flow here?

Here is my working **example** on displaying simple jsp page using **Spring 4.1v**.

```
@Controller
public class AboutUsController {
    @RequestMapping("/home.htm")
    public String showAboutUs() {
        return "entry";
    }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.span.controller")
// @EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig { // extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}

public class StartUp extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"*.htm"};
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-servlet-config. Does it work, yes, is it sufficient it might. But the version you use still has the old `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` instead of the newer more powerful/flexible `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and other classes.

Comment: Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you using SpringBoot?