# Spring boot index not loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got a Spring boot application.

I'm not using @EnableWebMvc and I've got my resources in the `src/main/resources/static` folder. When I try to load `localhost:8080/ui/` it just downloads a random file (type: octet-stream). If I directly use `/ui/index.html` it does work.

I'm also using a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but this does not seem to be the cause of problem.

Has anyone encountered this before? I would like it to load the index.html file when I request `localhost:8080/ui/`

[image: What I see when I load /ui/]

How I start my application:

```
package my.package;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

//@EnableWebMvc //Breaks js resource loading
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableZuulProxy
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>nl.jaarsma</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>my-application</name>
    <description>Example app</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Dalston.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>


<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId> -->
<!--            <scope>test</scope> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId> -->
<!--            <scope>test</scope> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>include-ui</id>
            <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>ui</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install node and npm</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <nodeVersion>v6.11.1</nodeVersion>
                                <npmVersion>3.10.10</npmVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>npm run build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>run build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                        <directory>ui/dist</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**</include>
                        </includes>
                        <targetPath>static/ui</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for not using `@EnableWebMvc`?

Comment: @Vasan Because it also seemed to break resource loading. Maybe there is a solution using WebMVC that works?

Comment: Try having an empty class marked with `@Controller`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work.

Comment: without seeing your source code, how would we know what's the issue?

Comment: @Vasan using EnableWebMvc will break spring boot default configuration. You shouldn't use it unless you have a strong reason to.

Comment: @eis what code would you like to see?

Comment: @Jelte how/where do you define that you deploy to `/ui`?

Comment: @eis I use a maven plugin to copy my ui resources to /static/ui. If I open my jar I can see my resources are indeed in the `BOOT-INF\classes\static\ui\` folder.

Comment: @Jelte I guess in your deployment configuration you're deploying the app to `/` and you just have static resources in the ui folder under that path. That would explain why it doesn't work. Is that intended?

Comment: @eis yes I am deploying my app to `/` and I just have static resources in my `/ui/` folder. That's intended. Why does this explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: try to use [addViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381781/java-spring-boot-how-to-map-my-app-root-to-index-html)

Answer (score 5):

Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories:  [Link](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)

```
/META-INF/resources/
/resources/
/static/
/public/
```

By default Spring Boot serves static content from resources in the classpath at "/static" (or "/public").

The index.html resource is special because it is used as a "welcome page" if it exists, which means it will be served up as the root resource, i.e. at http://localhost:8080/ in our example.  [Link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

for your case you need to tell spring location of your index.html

```
public class MyApplication {


    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/ui/").
                          addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/ui/index.html");
            }
        };
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this gives me a 404 when I try to load /ui/. Weird thing is, if I deploy my UI on the root: / instead of /ui/ it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are placing your static resources in the '/static/ui' you have to inform Spring Boot of this.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setOrder(-1)
        .addResourceHandler("/index.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/ui/");
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
}
```

If there are other files in `/static/ui` then you can use wildcards `/**`. See the Spring Blog for more details: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Comment: Personally, if there is a real business reason for not using the defaults, I would have the build process put the files in `/static` and save yourself the headache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this also didn't work (404). I also tried changing `/index.html` to `/ui/index.html`. I currently have solved this by putting my static resources directly in the resources folder, as you said in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a controller that maps `/ui` to `index.html`?

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/ui")
    public String home(Model model) {
         return "index.html";
    }
}
```

Also, you may need to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532859/how-does-requestmapping-work-without-enablewebmvc) link to enable it without `@EnableWebMVC`

Answer (score 1):

following this url https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

you can add static file pattern in application.properties without extra code.

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/** # Path pattern used for static resources.
```